# VBA Help. Simple code help. Make the activecell the first cell with value>100

Tags: excel, vba

I created a simple excel file with 1 column and 200 rows. Each cell contains an integer value.

I'm trying to create a VBA code that will automatically make the first cell with an integer value of over 100 the active cell.

This is the code that i came up with. My problem is that it does nothing :(

```
 Sub test1()

      Dim trial As Range
      Dim cell As Range

      Set trial = Range("A1:A100")

      For Each cell In trial          
           If cell > 100 Then
      End If         
      Next cell

 End Sub
```

Comment: just add "cell.Select" inside the if and then "Exit For" to stop the loop, otherwise will loop to 100 and the last cell with value > 100 will be selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

Always use `.Value` when working with a `Range` and you are wanting to use the `Cell` Value. As mentioned in a comment below @gizlmeier mentioned. Its good to get the smalls things like this right when you start programming for cleaner coding at a later stage.

Also you `Sub` will run and then stop without changing anything, but it does work. So you just need to add the `Activate` to the `If` statement and then decide to End just the `For` Loop or to `End` the `Sub`

```
 Sub test1()

      Dim trial As Range
      Dim cell As Range

      Set trial = Range("A1:A100")

      For Each cell In trial

           If cell > 100 Then
                cell.Activate
                'Exit For will exit the For Loop
                Exit For
                'End will stop the code from running
                End
           End If

      Next cell

 End Sub
```

Comment: @EtienV remember to select the answer which is most appropriate and then give it an up vote

Answer (score 2):

Without loops:

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim lngPos As Long

Set rng1 = [a1:a100]
lngPos = Evaluate("=MIN(IF(" & rng1.Address & ">100,ROW(" & rng1.Address & "),1000))")

If lngPos < rng1.cells.count Then Application.Goto rng1.Cells(lngPos)
```